# Call controller form another bean. No thread-bound request found

Tags: java, spring, controller, jms

I'm developing a spring mvc and i want my controller to listen application events
via @controller I send a jms message from a web page
and I'm trying to notify the controller when receiving a message jms, in order to push some data to a web page

First I've tried with the observer pattern, implementing the controller as an ApplicationListener

```
@ Controller ("MyController") 
@ Scope (value = "session" = proxyMode ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public class MyController implements Serializable, ApplicationListener <CustomEvent>
```

Then I've tried to call a controller method from another bean when receiving a jms message

```
@Resource(name="MyController")
private MyController c;
c.update(String data);
```

But I'm getting always the same error

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Is there a way to call a controller from another bean?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your controller is session-scoped, and you try to call its method from a context where no HTTP session is available.

So, I assume that your controller combines functionality that depends on HTTP session (thus `session` scope), and functionality that need to be called outside of a session (such as your `update()` method).

If so, you can solve this problem by moving functionality that doesn't require HTTP session into separate bean (without `session` scope).

Comment: the final goal is to notify a web page when i receive a jms message..
so i want to call a controller outside of http session